# extern struct not recognised in CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have following piece of code in one of my source file under a project in CDT(eclipse).

```
extern "C" {
void*   obj1(int size);     /* alloc uninit memory */
void*   obj2(int size);     /* alloc cleared memory */
void*   obj3(void*, int size);  /* extend memory, new mem is uninit */
void    obj4(void* ptr);
}
```

I am getting this error message "expected identifier or '(' before  string constants"
i think that compiler could not recognise it and i need to supply it with some flag for this purpose.please propose solution for it.It also gives the same message for another piece of code
    extern "C" { int NlvStrmatch(const char*, const char*, int); 
    }

Comment: i am using a linux tool chain with gcc compiler . does different version of compiler can give rise to this problem

Comment: after further searching for it i got this solution(incomplete).  #ifdef _cplusplus {extern "C" code } #endif it solved the problem of error in this but another file which is using this header could not identify this structure after this implementation. i am still struggling with the reason for this